# Calling Mathematica functions from Node js project. Similar to .NET by making Mathematica Kernel?

Tags: external-calls, javascript

How to call Mathematica functions from my Node js project?
Is there any way I can do it like we do in .NET by making mathematica kernel?

Comment: Hi @IrtizaHassan, welcome to Mathematica SE, In its current form your question is too broad. Please [edit] your question to give us more context. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? It will help you understand what is expected on this site to take the [tour] and search for similar questions on the site. Tell us in which way your question is different.